# Create Classes and Derived Classes in any folder of Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I want to ask some questions about the Zend framework. if someone knows please answer it will be a great help.

- **Q1.** Can we create classes, abstract and derived classes in any folder
  of the Zend Project?
- **Q2.** If Q1 answer is yes how we can database access (from the model
  class) or we need to utilize any other Zend related functionality.
- **Q3.** Is it possible to place abstract class and the implementation
  of an class within a dedicated folder somewhere within the source
  tree?

Comment: Are you referring to zf1 or zf3? Please, stop putting both tags and target only the correct version!

Comment: Okay Thanks, @Ermenegildo I did

Answer (score 1):

#### Q1 - Can we create classes, abstract and derived classes in any folder of the Zend Project?

Yes, you can, but it is not encouraged. Why? Because it would end up in a messy project, with a portion of code in a given location, other code somewhere else, other snippets in a third location.. This will make maintenance more complex than it should be, wasting time searching for the code between all different locations.

For this subject, I suggest you to read the [PSR-4 specifications and directives](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

That being said, let's make this example. You want to create a class `OutsideClass`, with namespace `OutsideCode`, in folder `outsideFolder`.

What you need to do is:

1. Create in the folder `outsideFilder`, which will be located in the root folder of your project.
2. Create the class `OutsideClass`:

```php
<?php

namespace OutsideCode;

class OutsideClass
{
    // ...
    // Class properties, constructor and methods
    // ...
}
```

3. Add the namespace inside the `composer.json`, so the application will be able to translate a namespace into a phisical location:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        ...
        "OutsideCode\\": "outsideFolder/"
    }
}
```

4. Run `composer dump-autoload` to recreate autoload file
5. End. You can now put all the code you want inside this folder, always respecting `PSR-4` directives
6. Use your new classes from your controller/mappers/forms/validators/...

```php
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use OutsideCode\OutsideClass;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $outsideClass = new OutsideClass();
    }
}
```

#### Q2 - If Q1 answer is yes how we can database access (from the model class) or we need to utilize any other Zend related functionality.

It is not mandatory to use Zend related functionalities.

Nobody prevents you to access your write all your code from scratch, using only PHP methods, to access the database, or to validate a phone number, or to send an email. If you want to use Zend functionalities (or classes that you already wrote), just import them with a `use` statement and the top of the file (as shown in the previous snippet).

The most important thing is always: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and [don't reinvent the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) ([+this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse))

#### Q3 - Is it possible to place abstract class and the implementation of an class within a dedicated folder somewhere within the source tree?

Yes, until its position follows [PSR-4 specifications and directives](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), otherwise it won't be loaded (nor executed)